# path parse and fitting in python

Tags: python

I need your help to solve this problem using python. I have a .txt file called good_files.txt within which each line is a path that leads to a new file (good_files.txt and the directory which contain the files are in the same directory) . In each of these files, there are three columns of data that I will have to unite all together to make the curve fitting
e.g the sctructure of the file is like this.

```
1000.415915     225.484744      -2.012516
2.000945

215     0       0
219     0       0
222     4       0
224     70      70
226     696     696
229     999     1000
233     1001    1000
238     1001    1000
```

So I have to eliminate the first 2 lines keeping the 3 columns and then eliminate the third colums, keeping only the first two.
The first colums is my `x` coordinates and the second column is contain my `y` coordinates.
With my `x and y` and the error function `erf` I have to do the `curve fitting`.

For now the only code that I have written is for reading the good_files.txt

```
    def ReadFromFile (fileName):
    sourceFile= open (fileName, 'r')
    text=[]
    for adress in sourceFile.readlines ():
        if '\n' in adress: text.append (adress [:-1])
        else: text.append (adress)
    return text
    sourceFile.close()
def WriteToFile (text):
    resultFile = open ('result.txt','w')
    for data in text:
        resultFile.write (data + '\n')
    resultFile.close()

adresses = ReadFromFile ('good_files.txt')
for adress in adresses:
    text = ReadFromFile (adress)
    WriteToFile(text)
```

Sorry but I am a noob in coding, for now. Thaks for your help, guys <3

Comment: hint: take a look at the methods of `str` [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)
probably the most interesting for you are `splitlines` and `split`
you could also google list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pandas to help reading and combining the csv-files. 
Assuming that your ReadFromFile function gives you a good list of filenames, you could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

def ReadFromFile (fileName):
    sourceFile= open (fileName, 'r')
    text=[]
    for adress in sourceFile.readlines ():
        if '\n' in adress: text.append (adress [:-1])
        else: text.append (adress)
    return text
    sourceFile.close()

adresses = ReadFromFile('claro_good_files.txt')
df_list = [] # create empty list that will hold your dataframes from the seperate csv's

for adress in adresses:
    # load each file, skipping the first two rows of data, splitting columns by whitespace, and setting the column names
    df_temp = pd.read_csv(adress, skiprows=2, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, names=['x', 'y', 'remove'])

    # add the 'x' and 'y' columns to the list of data frames to combine (exclude 'remove' column)
    df_list.append(df_temp[['x', 'y']])

df = pd.concat(df_list) # Combine all the DataFrame's into one big one
```

This should give you a dataframe with the `x` and `y` column.